# How to use Python to pipe a .htm file to a website

Tags: python, html

I have a file, `gather.htm` which is a valid HTML file with `header/body` and `forms`.  If I double click the file on the Desktop, it properly opens in a web browser, auto-submits the `form` data (via `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">document.forms[2].submit();</SCRIPT>`) and the page refreshes with the requested data.

I want to be able to have Python make a `requests.post(url)` call using `gather.htm`.  However, my research and my trail-and-error has provided no solution.

How is this accomplished?

I've tried things along these lines (based on examples found on the web). I suspect I'm missing something simple here!

```
myUrl = 'www.somewhere.com'
filename='/Users/John/Desktop/gather.htm'
f = open (filename)
r =  requests.post(url=myUrl, data =  {'title':'test_file'},  files =  {'file':f})
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

And:

```
htmfile = 'file:///Users/John/Desktop/gather.htm'
files = {'file':open('gather.htm')}
webbrowser.open(url,new=2)
response = requests.post(url)
print response.text
```

Note that in the 2nd example above, the `webbrowser.open()` call works correctly but the `requests.post` does not.

It appears that everything I tried failed in the same way - the URL is opened and the page returns default data. It appears the website never receives the `gather.htm` file.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML which describes the form?

Comment: What is the status code returned from your first block of code?

Comment: I shorten it and removed the URL. There are a couple other forms not shown, those the forms[2].submit() at the bottom.

Comment: <form action="http://"valid URL here"" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
         <p>
            Date
            <label for="day" class="hidden">Day</label>
            <select name="day" id="day" tabindex="8">
            <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
            </select>

   <input type="hidden" name="set_time" value="search">
            <button type="submit" name="set_time_button" tabindex="13">Search</button>
         </p>
       </form>
       
       <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">document.forms[2].submit();</SCRIPT>
  </body>

Comment: Had to shorten it even more to get it to fit. Doesn't appear well on my end - not sure how to post it it in 'pretty' format.

Comment: 200 since the website is OK with loading a default page (that is, a page withOUT the form data).

Answer (score 0):

Since your request is returning `200 OK`, there is nothing wrong getting your post request to the server. It's hard to give you an exact answer, but the problem lies with how the server is handling the request. Either your post request is being formatted in a way that the server doesn't recognise, or the server hasn't been set up to deal with them at all. If you're managing the website yourself, some additional details would help.

Just as a final check, try the following:

```
r = requests.post(url=myUrl, data={'title':'test_file', 'file':f})
```

Comment: No luck with that. I don't have control of the server which makes this hard.  I think it's in the data={} section - it expects different values but I don't know what.  But if I open myFile.htm in a browser, it does work OK.  That tells me the HTML file is properly formatted - it just doesn't get to the website properly when Python tries to pass it along.